# SharePoint 2010 - Attach 2007 Content DB (Site Definition???)

Tags: migration, upgrade

We have attached a 2007 content db to a 2010 instance of SharePoint and now...the site is not using the default.aspx that is in the file system.

In fact, I am not sure which default.aspx page it is using.  I had expected that after the migration it would be using the site definition default.aspx and the customMasterpage which is located in the site definition.

I have confirmed via the database that it is using the appropriate site definition (web template and configuration id) however it seems to be using some other default.aspx and it is ignoring the custom master page designation in the onet.xml file.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Before you attach the content database, run the PowerShell command Test-SPContentDatabase. This will generate a report that will flag up any missing artefacts or other dependencies and problems in your farm.

You can also run the stsadm -o preupgradecheck command on your 2007 farm (requires SP2).